# JavaScript not getting function returns in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, return

I have made an IRC bot for purely learning purposes but I have a Minecraft server that I use an API to get the status back as JSON. Now I have made the code and it works but for some reason when I try and use a return on the function so I can get the content it seems to not work?

So I have the two functions below:

```
    function getservers(name) {
        if (name == "proxy") {
            var Request = unirest.get(proxy);

            Request.header('Accept', 'application/json').end(function (response) {
              main = response["raw_body"];
              data = JSON.parse(main);
              console.log(data["motd"]);
              return data.motd;
            });
        } else if (name == "creative") {
            var Request = unirest.get(creative);

            Request.header('Accept', 'application/json').end(function (response) {
              main = response["raw_body"];
              data = JSON.parse(main);
              return data;
            });
        } else if (name == "survival") {
            var Request = unirest.get(survival);

            Request.header('Accept', 'application/json').end(function (response) {
              main = response["raw_body"];
              data = JSON.parse(main);
              return data;
            });
        }
    }

    // Main logic:
    function parsemessage(msg, to) {
        // Execute files
        function pu(o,t,f){if(o)throw o;if(f)throw f;bot.say(to,t)}
        if (msg.substring(0,1) == pre) {
            // Get array
            msgs = msg.split(' ');

            console.log(msgs[0]);

            // Run Login
            if (msgs[0] == pre+"help") {
                bot.say(to, "Help & Commands can be found here: https://server.dannysmc.com/bots.html");
            } else if (msgs[0] == pre+"status") {
                // Get status of server, should return online/offline - player count for each server - motd

                server = getservers("proxy");
                console.log(server);

                /*var data = '';

                var Request = unirest.get('https://mcapi.us/server/status?ip=185.38.149.35&port=25578');

                Request.header('Accept', 'application/json').end(function (response) {
                  main = response["raw_body"];
                  data = JSON.parse(main);
                });


            } else if (msgs[0] == pre+"players") {
                // Should return the player list for each server



            } else if (msgs[0] == pre+"motd") {
                // Should return the message of the day.



            } else if (msgs[0] == pre+"ip") {
                bot.say(to, "ShinexusUK IP Address: shinexusuk.nitrous.it");        
            } else if (msgs[0] == pre+"rules") {

            }
        }
    }
```

The code in the getservers() function works, when I do the

```
console.log(data["motd"]);
```

It outputs my servers message of the day. But when I do return

```
data.motd
```

(same as data["motd"]?) The code that calls the function is here

```
server = getservers("proxy");
console.log(server);
```

Please note this is a node.js code and it contains many files so i can't exactly paste it. So here is the link to the github repo with the whole node application: [Here](https://github.com/dannysmc95/ircbot_server)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Hacketo I do not think it is that,if you actually read the code it waits until the call comes back before it carries on the code? It uses a .end(function() {}) at the end.

Comment: the `return data` are in a callback, your function `getservers` actually returns nothing, it's a duplicate, you will find your answer in this post

Comment: @Hacketo I am new to JavaScript so I do not know what you mean, reading through the post I am not sure how that works either, I use the unirest library? So I copied what it does? Is there any MORE information that you can supply that will help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the function `getservers` is called, it makes an asynchronous request and return nothing.
Then the callback is fired with the response of that request as parameter.

Note that the function `getservers` will end before the `end` callback of your request is called

(simplified version)

```
function getservers(name) {
    var Request = unirest.get(proxy);

    Request.header('Accept', 'application/json').end(function (response) {
        main = response["raw_body"];
        data = JSON.parse(main);
        console.log(data["motd"]);
        return data.motd;
    });

    // nothing returned here
}
```

---

What you need is a function callback that will be called after you got the response.

```
function getservers(name, callback) { // callback added
    var Request = unirest.get(proxy);

    Request.header('Accept', 'application/json').end(function (response) {
        main = response["raw_body"];
        data = JSON.parse(main);
        console.log(data["motd"]);
        callback(data.motd);    // fire the callback with the data as parameter
    });

    // nothing returned here
}
```

And then you can use your function like this :

```
getservers("proxy", function(server){

     console.log(server);

     ....
})
```

Comment: Awesome thank you, I got there in the end, but this is the correct answer.